Which indefinite article should be used before a period followed by a vowel: "a(n) .ir domain"?
I am writing an email and I just realized I am a bit baffled.  I do not think there is a proper convention to this, unless there is and I have not heard of it.  This is in regards to registering domain names, like .com, .net, .org, etc.

We cannot register a .ir domain.

or

We cannot register an .ir domain.

I guess it comes down to whether you 'say' the dot before the domain name.

The a/an choice is totally (except in the disputed area illustrated by a/an hotel with unaspirated 'h') governed by pronunciation. And some feel it should be totally governed by pronunciation.

The "dot" is usually pronounced (e.g. "the dot-com bubble"), so "a" is correct.

I did some research and see both "a .edu" and "an .edu" in use. While it might be more common to pronounce the dot, particularly with .com/"dot com", it's not mandatory and not always necessary. There isn't going to be an official rule for this.

I think you've answered in your OP.  It's a if you say dot and 'an' if you don't.
